# How to store a frame to a file using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video, frame

I am reading frames from a camera using:

`capture=cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
 frame1 = cv.QueryFrame(capture)`

How can I save this frame into a jpg file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
cv.SaveImage("frame.jpg". ,frame1);
```